# get pair of record from group by clause

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have some table from that table I fetch record using

```
string_agg(a2.sampl_no, ', ') as sampl_nos
```

and group by clause which will work fine but I want to get each row have maximum 4 sample_no aggrgate.

Suppose From Database I got

```
string_agg as (0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005, 0006)
```

in one row but i want this

```
(0001, 0002, 0003, 0004) (0006, 0007).
```

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Since you tagged this PHP, you can use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: yes, array_chunk() also can used. thank you for give suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in the database, you can break the records into groups of four with `row_number()` and then use `string_agg()`:

```
select * from rec_agg;
┌───────────┐
│ sample_no │
├───────────┤
│ 0001      │
│ 0002      │
│ 0003      │
│ 0004      │
│ 0005      │
│ 0006      │
│ 0007      │
│ 0008      │
│ 0009      │
│ 0010      │
│ 0011      │
└───────────┘
(11 rows)


with mk_grp as (
  select *, ((row_number() over (order by sample_no)) - 1) / 4 as grp 
    from rec_agg
) 
select string_agg(sample_no, ' ,') 
  from mk_grp 
 group by grp ;
┌────────────────────────┐
│       string_agg       │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 0001 ,0002 ,0003 ,0004 │
│ 0009 ,0010 ,0011       │
│ 0005 ,0006 ,0007 ,0008 │
└────────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks a lot its help me to solve issue. Have a good day.